# WPBakery Do you know where models are created?

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I want to save my models (WPBakery option) and use them again for others projects.

So i try to find where WPBakery save them, I searched them by the title, but no result in the BDD and in the files of the project...

Maybe someone here know how this work ? I repeat again, my purpose is to save them and reload them in another project.